# Parsing XML using Digester

Tags: java, xml, apache-commons-digester

I have a xml and it has a list tag with number of items.

Example:

```
    <param>
       <id>12345</id>
       <date>2012/07/10</date>
       <list>
         <item>
           <name>Test1</name>
           <code>C1</code>
         </item>
         <item>
           <name>Test2</name>
           <code>C2</code>
         </item>
       </list>
    </param>
```

I want to map this in to Java a object using Jakarta Digester framework.

My plan is this.

1. Create a main ResponseDTO
2. Create a ItemDTO
3. Add a ItemDTO Array List to ResponseDTO

So after parsing this xml to Jakarta Digester engine I'm expectibg a ResponseDTO with ItemDTO list which are having real values.

Could some one kindly let me know how I can do this using Digester framework.

Comment: will you be able to use xtsream ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have a look to this article: http://www.devx.com/Java/Article/21832

But there are dozen of XML de/serialization frameworks that are much more user friendly... (http://x-stream.github.io/tutorial.html#init).

M.